# Broken Packages Issue while installing JDK on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, java, jdk

I am having issues while trying to install JDK on Ubuntu 14.04. Following is what I see:

```
araj1@araj:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openjdk-6-jre : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did try using synaptic to resolve this issue but when I try to install the package it shows error of broken package and does not install. Can someone please help here?